# Stopping SceneView Animation Triggered by User Interaction Through a Function Call

Tags: swift, scenekit

When a user changes the position, orientation, rotation, or transform of the sceneView's pointOfView (allowsCameraControl is true), they can stop this by clicking once on the sceneView. How can I achieve this with a function call?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this, if your goal is to stop the automatic rotation of the `POV` with `allowsCameraControl` with a function call.

(in this basic example: stop the movement after 0.5 sec)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.cameraNode.transform = self.scnView.pointOfView!.transform
        self.scnView.pointOfView = self.cameraNode
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you want to achieve, but it will stop the camera rotation.

*(the automatic rotation comes from an internal SceneKit generated camera object, when `allowsCameraControl` is set to true, it is in fact not the cameraNode that is moved or rotated.)*